# Porting code from iOS Xcode to Android (Parsing XML SAX)

Tags: android, ios, xml, parsing, sax

I am trying to port an app form iOS to Android. I am new to Parsing XML in Android. Could you please give me a hand?

Here's a taste of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
    <settingA>1</settingA>
    <settingB>sunday</settingB>
    <description>HAdijoijaofijfosdifjsoidfjodsfjidsfojds</description>
   </item>
</items>
```

In iOS I follow some steps that include finding and reading an element such as:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"terms"]) {
        // Tag <terms> found, creating a list of oracoes
        self.terms= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"term"]) {
        // Tag <term> found, creating a new Term object
        term = [[Term alloc] init];
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"terms"])
    {

        return;
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"term"]) {

        [self.oracoes addObject:term];

        [term release];
        term = nil;
    } else {

        if(tempString != nil && term != nil){
            [oracao setValue:tempString forKey:elementName];
        }

        [tempString release];
        tempString = nil;
    }
}

// Read content
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *s = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet     whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if(!tempString)
    {

        tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    [tempString appendString:s];
}
```

Maybe all of this code is irrelevant... but anyway... where should I start from?
Is there any straightforward to pase this XML information to a list, array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate when people answer this way but....

I recently ran into the same situation where I needed to create an android version of my iphone app. Instead of picking one of android zillion parsing methods, I used a framework that abstracted it a way a bit. If Apache license is not an issue, I strongly recommend this.

[Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) will map xml to your objects.

Comment: +1 for Simple XML. Outstanding in its simplicity and power.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I will post what I did here!

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmlpullparser is quite easy to do. Refer the link below, it has an sample code
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html